# How can Groovy Beans standard constructors deal with null values?

Tags: groovy, javabeans, null

I am trying to build a microsimulation model with Groovy, but I am stuck with a problem that I traced back to Groovy’s handling of null values in Groovy Bean constructors.

In short, the [constructor method that Groovy offers](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Beans)

```
new Person(nrLegs:calculationResult1, nrArms:calculationResult2)
```

throws an `IllegalArgumentException` if one of the calculation results is null, which is how I thought missing survey data would be best represented.

This is what seems strange to me: If I define a variable `double age;` without value, it is set to null, obviously.

```
double testDouble;
assert testDouble == null; // no Problem
```

If I do the same with Groovy beans, it has a value of 0.0, e.g:

```
class Person {
double age;
int nrLegs, nrArms;
}
```

then

```
Person testPerson = new Person(nrArms:calculationResult1) 
assert testPerson.age == null; // Assertion failed. testPerson.age == 0.0
```

Furthermore, I cannot set properties to null using the Groovy syntax:

```
Person testPerson = new Person(nrArms:calculationResult1) 
testPerson.age = null; // IllegalArgumentException
```

This seems to be exactly the same problem as above.

Why would Groovy forbid me to assign null values?

Thanks for your help!

**Edit**: for reference, here are [the entire Person class](http://pastebin.com/6X7XEg6Z) and the [StackTrace](http://pastebin.com/TMjtjQCu).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to assign `null` to a bean property of `int` type.

`int` is a primitive type. It's not an object, and so is not nullable : it has to have a value. These are the same rules as for Java - the primitive types are `int`, `float`, `boolean`, `double`, `char`... . On object creation, a primitive property is initialized to 0, 0.0, false, etc.

If you need to represent 'no data', then it's probably best to edit the class definition so that the bean property uses the corresponding object wrapper type - in this case`Integer` - which can then be set to `null`.

If you're unable to edit the class, then common work arounds are to use some kind of marker value - e.g. `-1`, or `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, or somesuch. But then logic that manipulates the Person class needs to  understand the significance of the marker value

Comment: Changing the type of the variables from `int` to `Integer` really solved the issue, thank you! However, that raises the question **why**? Firstly, [Groovy does not have primitive data types](http://www.vogella.de/articles/Groovy/article.html#datatypes). Secondly, "primitive" data types (such as `double`) _can_ be set to null in Groovy, as the first example I provided shows. Is this a bug?

Comment: sure, Groovy doesn't have primitive types - but isn't your Person class Java? (I can't tell without seeing the file suffix - is it `.java`? - it certainly looks like Java). Groovy has to interoperate with compiled java classes by automatically `unboxing` (converting between Objects and primitive types). It's this unboxing that was causing your original IllegalArgumentException.

You might be able to avoid all this by making sure your `Person` class is compiled as groovy, not java.

Comment: The file extension is `.groovy`, not `.java`. I am not sure whether it is compiled as Groovy, but I suppose it is, since otherwise the method `new Person(age:xyz,nrCond:xyz)` would not work, would it?

Comment: I'm asking about the file where the Person class is defined (the file you put up on pastebin), not the file where the person object is instantiated (where new Person(..) is called)

Comment: Yes, that’s the one I meant. It has a `.groovy` extension.